# Please fix the minor glitches in example newsletter

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

Here are some of the issues that I encountered with example newsletter section that appears on the right side, if you haven't subscribed to newsletter. All the below mentioned scenarios were generated on Google Chrome browser 12.0.742.122.

- I always right-click on links and open them in new tab. Anyways, that doesn't work on the link example newsletter because it's a pop-up. If I select Open link in new tab or Open link in new window, I am just redirected to the main page. It is a minor annoyance for me but I can certainly adjust. This is not the issue.

[image]

- In the example newsletter, layout is nice. **Perfect.**
- Clicking on the post link (a), the content is displayed on a new browser tab. **Perfect.**
- Clicking on any of the user profile links (b & c), the content is displayed on a new browser tab. **Perfect.**
- However, clicking on a tag (d), throws the message `For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.` and eventually closes the newsletter and opens the tag content on the same browser tab. Is there anyway to make this work the way other links function?

[image: News letter]

[image: frames]

- Clicking the link `Subscribe to more Stack Exchange newsletters` (a) displays the Stack Exchange website within the popup instead of opening a new window.
- Are the links `Unsubscribe from this newsletter` (b), `subscriptions page on stackexchange.com` (c), `unsubscribe from all stackexchange.com emails` (d) that appear at the bottom of the newsletter suppose to point to the newsletter itself?
- I thought the links should lead to an appropriate page on the Stack Exchange website.
- feedback site link works correctly by opening up the meta website in a new browser tab.

[image: Links]

[image: SE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added `target="_blank"` to the newsletter links that didn't already have it, so the tag and "subscribe to more newsletters" links open in a new tab/window now.

Additionally, the "example newsletter" link's `href` attribute now points to the newsletter page, so you can open it in a new tab.

As for your final concern: we realize it's slightly confusing, but it's [status-by-design] that the unsubscribe links don't actually work – how would one unsubscribe from the newsletter preview?

Thanks for the extensive write-up.