# Links in newsletter preview link to YouTube

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange, newsletter, youtube

The problem:
The links at the bottom of the Stack Exchange newsletter link to a YouTube video instead of the right place on the website. I´m not sure if this is an oversight or a clever hack.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Here is the offending link - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkfVdrtLcRs and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY

Comment: Link to the newsletter page so you can see for yourself - http://stackexchange.com/newsletters

Comment: I requested the devs to point the link to somewhere else but didn't realize they would choose Youtube. :-) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100852/please-fix-the-minor-glitches-in-example-newsletter

Comment: mhh its funny that they changed the links to youtube. the first thing i thought after seeing it was: "wow did they get hacked?" linking back to the newsletter seems better

Comment: I don't see any youtube links.

Comment: @John: Are you looking for the YouTube links in the newsletter email that you receive?

Comment: @Siva: No, I thought they were in the newsletter *preview* as per the title.  Are they only in the email? (I haven't subscribed to any newsletters yet.)

Comment: @John: No, those links are in the preview. I can still see the links to YouTube. The links are at the bottom of the newsletter.

Comment: Ah!  Found them!  Thanks @Siva.  Judging by the content of those videos, I think that was intentional.  (How exactly would you "properly" implement an "Unsubsribe" button on an example?)

Comment: @John: It used to redirect to itself. I suggested redirecting the links to SE newsletter home page. Now, I guess we are kind of Rick Rolled. ;-)

Comment: @Siva: Gotta watch those tricky SE people!  (BTW, this question is *SO* much clearer now that I'm looking at it from a computer that doesn't block imgur!)

Answer (score 21):

This is by design, since those links can't work in the preview.

So instead we made them link somewhere.. fun.

Comment: Since this is by design, can we vote on the videos that you link to?  :)

Comment: I was hoping this would be the answer.