# Are YouTube links in the newsletter preview a bug or an easter egg?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, newsletter, popups, easter-eggs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links in newsletter preview link to YouTube](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101334/links-in-newsletter-preview-link-to-youtube)

Go to any non-beta SE site (e.g. [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/)).  Go to the sidebar and find the newsletter panel (if you’ve already subscribed, you’ll need to do this on another site).  Click “see an example newsletter”.  Scroll all the way to the end of the sample newsletter and click either the “unsubscribe from this newsletter” link or the “subscriptions page on stackexchange.com” link.  Each of the links takes you to YouTube: the first to [this vid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHy7DGLTt8g), and the second to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY).

Is this a bug or an easter egg?

Comment: Why do you assume it's either?

Comment: Because the links say they're going to take you somewhere that they don't actually take you.  If it was an accident, then it's a bug.  If it was done on purpose, then it's an easter egg.

Comment: You forgot the [third](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkfVdrtLcRs) link (unsubscribe from all stackexchange.com emails.)

Comment: Oh, and the [fourth link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (our feedback site).  Maybe that was an easter egg too?

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe.

Comment: *And* an easter egg!

Comment: I just assumed you had to watch the video until the end to unsubscribe.  Boy is my face red. ;)