# Newsletter page links points to worst video on Youtube

Tags: support, newsletter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Links in newsletter preview link to YouTube](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101334/links-in-newsletter-preview-link-to-youtube)

On the [Stack Exchange newsletter page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=askubuntu.com) there exists a link titled "your subscriptions page on stackexchange.com.". The link points to a [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY). I suggest that this link (and the link before it on the same page) be fixed, as I wasted quite a bit of time watching that entire video and it ended without a single mention of my Stack Exchange subscriptions page.

Comment: Strangely enough it's not the only link to a youtube video on that footer. Either some dev/test version has escaped into the wild, or this is someone's idea of a joke.

Comment: I love this video!!!

Comment: @BoltClock, This question was pointing out that the video linked to was useless, not that it linked to a video, so it's not a duplicate.