# Trying to unsubscribe from weekly newsletter leads to... YouTube 10 hours show

Tags: bug, newsletter, youtube

That's the weirdest bug I have ever encountered or reported... and there were many.

First spotted in Science Fiction & Fantasy site, clicked "example newsletter" and in [there it is](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=scifi.stackexchange.com):

> [image]

The "Subscribe to more Stack Exchange newsletters" is still fine, but all following links marked in red are leading to: (in order of appearance)

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q44qwyHlMfk
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGFz5v_P2ug (removed)
3. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6LzEbuI7e8

This is the case in the newsletter **for all sites**, though I didn't yet check the actual email. (guess it's the same though)

Is this a dev-joke forgotten in the source code? Has Friday arrived in Iceland?

## P.S.

Turns out [this is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101401/152859) since it's only preview thus can't be unsubscribed from. Fair enough, but can the removed vid be replaced then?

Comment: Hey, come on. Can't we have some fun? :(

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm the official fun buster! ;-)

Comment: Oops, didn't find the dupe while searching, saw it now.

Comment: Wait, you opened a new question then voted to close it as a dupe? :P

Comment: @James yes, didn't find the dupe at first.

Comment: Ship happens...